# docker nginx redirect based on http_accept_language

Tags: nginx, dockerfile, http-accept-language

I have a static website where I want to create a redirection depending on the browser language. The website runs in a docker using nginx and is built as follows:

nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 4;
error_log /dev/stderr info;
pid       /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    root /usr/share/nginx/my-app;

    map $http_accept_language $myindex {
        default index.html;
        ~*^fr.*  index.fr.html;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            rewrite .* $myindex;
        }
    }

}
```

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html; 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

dockerfile

```
# nginx
FROM nginx:1.17.5-alpine

COPY src /var/www
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
```

As soon as I go to the localhost the following problem occurs:
en -> index.html
en -> index.html (Expected: index.de.html)

Comment: You have two `server` blocks. Is the `rewrite` supposed to be in the default `server` block?

Comment: i can also write the rewrite to the default but then accept_header wouldn't work anymore, would it?